# mktime causing overflowError due to daylight savings time

Tags: python, mktime

I'm currently getting an Overflow error on the following code when daylight savings is set to true.  I've tried a number of date/time combinations and it appears to only be the 9th parameter ("is_dst") being set to "1" which is triggering the issue. The python versions tested on were 3.8.10.final.0 and 3.10.12.final.0 on databricks.

Is there anything peculiar around daylight savings time that could cause the issue - I don't believe that anything about the dates should lead to an overflow error

```
import time
time.mktime(time.struct_time((2023, 10, 5, 12, 0, 0, 6, 68, -1)))
1696507200.0
time.mktime(time.struct_time((2023, 10, 5, 12, 0, 0, 6, 68, 0)))
1696507200.0
time.mktime(time.struct_time((2023, 10, 5, 12, 0, 0, 6, 68, 1)))
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

More explicit version

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)  # UTC time
dt = utc_dt.astimezone()  # local time

btz = pytz.timezone("Australia/Brisbane") # currently +10
stz = pytz.timezone("Australia/Sydney") # currently +11

#brisbane
d1 = datetime.now(btz)
print(d1)
x1= d1.timetuple()
print(x1)
time.mktime(x1)
#sydney
d2 = datetime.now(stz)
print(d2)
x2= d2.timetuple()
print(x2)
time.mktime(x2)
```

The output is

```
2023-10-06 11:35:10.010458+10:00
time.struct_time(tm_year=2023, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=6, tm_hour=11, tm_min=35, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=279, tm_isdst=0)
2023-10-06 12:35:10.010884+11:00
time.struct_time(tm_year=2023, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=6, tm_hour=12, tm_min=35, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=279, tm_isdst=1)
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

This became an issue earlier this week when Sydney switched from AEST to AEDT (daylight savings time). The server is set to this timezone

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 3.7.2 or 3.11.5. I get no exception on either of those versions.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `mktime` makes a system call to the underlying platform, so it has nothing to do with the Python version.

Comment: As blhsing mentioned, `mktime` call underlying library and It is platform dependent. 
Running this code on my local machine doesn't return any error.

Comment: I shortened the code to try to show the basics of the error. I've added the more expressive code that shows the generation of the datetime and specifying of timezone - and that there was no explicit setting of tm_isdt

Answer (score 0):

`mktime` calls the underlying C library, and It is platform dependent.

The `tm_isdst` parameter is used to indicate whether Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect for the given time. When tm_isdst is set to 1, it signifies that DST is in effect, and this can cause issues in the `time.mktime` function, especially if it interacts with the system's DST settings.

To avoid this issue, you should generally avoid setting tm_isdst to 1 when creating a struct_time. Instead, let Python handle the DST information automatically based on your system's settings.

Comment: Thanks - good information however as per edited code above - I was not explicitely setting tm_isdst to 1 - it was being implicitely set via datetime.now(stz) which uses the timezone. stz was sydney time (where daylight saving is in effect). btz- brisbane time (where daylight savings is not in effect). using btz worked as tm_isdst was 0, and stz didn't as tm_isdst was 1, which you explain can be an issue - I would like to know why it could be an issue as this is something it appears to be explicitely set up to handle